# Pass an instance of an object in each loop from thymeleaf html file to Spring controller

Tags: java, spring, thymeleaf

I have a problem with passing an instance of "threads" in each loop from thymeleaf to Spring controller using a submit button. I'm trying to solve this by using the annotation @ModelAttribute, but one more instance of MessageThread is creating.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org" xmlns:form="http://www.w3.org/1999/html">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Форум</title>
</head>
    <body>

        <form method="post">
            <input type="text" name="header">
            <input type="text" name="text">
            <button name="newThread" type="submit">Создать тред</button>
        </form>

        <table>
            <thead>
            <tr>
                <th> Тред </th>
                <th> ОП пост </th>
            </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
            <tr th:if="${threads.isEmpty()}">
                <td colspan="2"> Нет доступных тредов </td>
            </tr>
            <div>
                <th:block th:each="thread : ${threads}">
                    <td th:type="id"><span th:text="${thread.getId()}"></span></td>
                    <td><span th:text="${thread.getHeader()}"> Title </span></td>
                    <td><span th:text="${thread.getText()}"> Title </span></td>
                    <form th:object="${thread}" th:method="post">
                        <td><button name="inThread" type="submit">В тред</button></td>
                    </form>
                </th:block>
            </div>
            </tbody>
        </table>

    </body>
</html>
```

I can't find a way to pass an instance of "threads" from thymeleaf. All that I want is to press Submit button and pass the ${thread} to "toThread" method.

My controller:

```
@Controller
public class ThreadController {

private final MessageService messageService;

@Autowired
public ThreadController(MessageService messageService) {
    this.messageService = messageService;
}

@GetMapping("/")
public String showThreads(Model model)
{
    model.addAttribute("threads", messageService.getThreads());
    return "threads-view";
}

@PostMapping(value = "/", params = "newThread")
public String addThread(Model model,
                        @RequestParam("header") String header,
                        @RequestParam("text") String text)
{
    model.addAttribute("threads", messageService.getThreads());
    messageService.addThread(header, text);
    return "redirect:/";
}

@PostMapping(value = "/", params = "inThread")
public String toThread(@ModelAttribute("thread") MessageThread thread) {
    System.out.println(thread.getId() + " " + thread.getHeader());
    return "redirect:/thread:";
}
```

}

MessageThread class:

```
package com.project.imageboard.model;

 import java.util.ArrayList;
 import java.util.List;

 public class MessageThread {

private String header;
private String text;
private int id;

private List<Message> messages = new ArrayList<>();

public MessageThread(String header, String text) {
    this.header = header;
    messages.add(new Message(text));
    this.text = text;
    this.id = messages.get(0).getId();
}

public int getId() {
    return id;
}
public String getText() {
    return text;
}
public String getHeader() {
    return header;
}

public List<Message> getMessages() {
    return messages;
}

public void insertMessage(Message message){
    messages.add(message);
}
```

}

I would be grateful for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your controller seems to be ok, you are mapping a post request to "/" and expecting to receive a MessageThread object which has to be built from the content of the request, the problem is in the template: you are not sending the data in the request from the client to the server, so spring has no way to assign the correct values to a new instance of MessageThread.

If we take this block from your template:

```
<th:block th:each="thread : ${threads}">
    <td th:type="id"><span th:text="${thread.getId()}"></span></td>
    <td><span th:text="${thread.getHeader()}"> Title </span></td>
    <td><span th:text="${thread.getText()}"> Title </span></td>
    <form th:object="${thread}" th:method="post">
        <td><button name="inThread" type="submit">В тред</button></td>
    </form>
</th:block>
```

1) The form tag is missing the action attribute, try adding something like `th:action="@{/}"` to target your request mapping on the server side.

2) You are not sending the actual content of the thread object to the server, for this you have to add input tags with the name of the imput matching the name of the field in the MessageThread object you want to populate. Something like the following:

```
<input type="hidden" th:field="*{header}" />
<input type="hidden" th:field="*{text}" />
```

In this example `th:field` is creating the `name` and `value` attributes for the input tags so you don't need to do it manually.

To sum up, there is no way to pass an actual "instance" of an object from the html running in the client to the java app running on the server, you can only send data using HTTP and parse that data on the server. The `ModelAttribute` annotation is instructing Spring to inspect an object (`MessageThread` in this case) and find in the data sent through the request the matching values to populate the object.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. It has become much clearer. But now I have a new problem. I added this `<input type="hidden" th:field="*{getId()}" />` and now I have the error `Error during execution of processor 'org.thymeleaf.spring5.processor.SpringInputGeneralFieldTagProcessor' (template: "threads-view" - line 33, col 46)`.

Comment: In `th:field` try using the name of the property in the java object instead of calling getId(): `th:field="*{id}"`. Thymeleaf will internally call the `getId` method.

Comment: There is still an error. I tried to use other values like `*{header}` and `*{text}` and the result is the same. When I click on the `newThread` button, the error appears. Maybe something is wrong with my Spring Boot version?

Comment: Mmm... i don't see it as a problem with spring, the error is specific to thymeleaf. But, looking again at the controller you shuld remove `params = "inThread"`.
Also, and most important, in the template check that you are adding the input fields inside the `<form>` tag. Also the syntax `*{id}` will only work inside the tag with `th:object`.

Comment: As an example based on your template:
```
<form th:object="${thread}" th:method="post">
    <input type="hidden" th:field="*{header}" />
    <input type="hidden" th:field="*{text}" />
    <td><button type="submit">В тред</button></td>
</form>
```

Comment: In general, the problem is that, in my case thymeleaf is not able to work with `th:field`. Solved the problem as follows: instead of `th:field` I used `th: name` and `th:value`. Now it looks like this: `<td><input type="hidden" th:name="threadId" th:value="*{id}"></td>`. The controller method now looks like this: `@PostMapping(value = "/", params = "inThread")
    public String toThread(@RequestParam("threadId") String thread)`. 
Maybe this is not the cleanest solution, but I only needed to get the ID field. Thank you very much for your help, I understood how to act in such situations.

Comment: Glad to help, just for information if th:field is not working in general is probably because you are not using the spring integration, you can find documentation on how to configure it here: https://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/tutorials/3.0/thymeleafspring.html (probably in section 4.3 Spring MVC configuration).